# Django and Parsley.js - works only for email field

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, validation, parsley.js

I need to validate a Django form on the client side, so I decided to use Parsley. But... Validation works only for email. I am not able to validate other fields such as login or password.

Here is some of my code related to this problem.

**template**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/parsley.js"></script>
```

...

```
<form data-parsley-validate method="post" action="register">
```

**form**:

```
from parsley.decorators import parsleyfy

@parsleyfy
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
  username = forms.CharField(label="Login:",min_length=3,max_length=30,required=True)
  email = forms.EmailField(label="Email:")
  password1 = forms.CharField(label="Hasło:",widget=forms.PasswordInput())
  password2 = forms.CharField(label="Powtórz hasło:",widget=forms.PasswordInput())
  phone = forms.CharField(label="Telefon:",max_length=20,required=False)
  log_on = forms.BooleanField(label="Logowanie po rejestracji:",required=False)
```

**Rendered**:

```
<labelr="id_username">Login:</label>
<input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" data-parsley-required-message="To pole jest wymagane." data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-minlength="3" data-parsley-maxlength="30">

<label for="id_email">Email:</label>
<input id="id_email" type="email" name="email" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-required-message="To pole jest wymagane." data-parsley-required="true">
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l04w3.png

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean with "validations doesn't work"? It doesn't show messages? It simply doesn't heck for the conditions?

Comment: Are you sure that is parsley validation?It seems to me this is HTML5 validation, not parsley on you picture

Comment: @Nahuel Ianni: when I click submit button it post form even when it's invalid. It shows error only if i put wrong email.

Comment: @fly_ua: I'm not sure, you might be right. I don't even know how to check it.

Comment: basically Parsley gives you error messages like 'Invalid email', but html5 highlights fields. You can try to use FireBug or other JS debugging tool to see what happens, because the question is very generic and there may be alot of reasons why it is not working. Also it is worth looking at working parsley examples http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html

Comment: @fly_ua: you're right, Parsley doesn't work at all. I based my form on parsley examples, both scripts(jquery and parsley) are loaded (I can see them i Firebug). 
Whis is how I generate my form:
http://i.imgur.com/fymbK3f.png

Comment: Parsley relies on jQuery (>= 1.8), and it would need to be included before including Parsley.  - Are you ok with jq version and files order?

Comment: yes, I included both in correct order. jquery-2.1.1.js and then parsley.js

Comment: Hard, to say what is going in, but did you try Javascript installation - with $('#form').parsley(); instead of basic ? Does it work?

Comment: in Javascript installation it also doesn't work. Is there any possibility that I have to enable JavaScript in Django?

Comment: I am not sure about django - i think the requirement is having these 2 js files in your web page + enable JS in browser. Can you send me something like your browser + firebug screenshot?

Comment: I don't know why but it started to work after changing parsley.js to parsley.min.js
Thank you very much, it's enough for me.